# What is 'Editable' data type in Android?

Tags: android

The `getText()` method returns `Editable` datatype. Why does it not return `String` data type? What is the difference between `Editable` and `String` data type? I read about the Editable datatype on developers site, but I didn't understand properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get string data easily just add

```
submitbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String text = edittext.getText().toString();
    }
});
```

Comment: and editable datatype means a data that could be changed ... it can be used for search suggestion kind of things.

Comment: What do you mean by "search suggestion kind of things"?

Comment: it means a developer can set response on text change in the edit box.

Like when you type in google search box it shows suggestion that's kind of the same thing.

Comment: One more doubt, please correct me if I am wrong. Won't we always convert `Editable` to `String` datatype? So why do we have an `editable` datatype?

Comment: String is an immutable class, Editable is just an interface. So String is pretty limited while Editable has countless of possible implementations. Following the fact that it is meant to be edited and the fact that Strings are immutable I would assume that Android developers tried to make Editable implementations better in terms of editing and changing the data. Changing data in String basically creates new String which may be very limiting factor and is an expensive operation. In the end if you need a String object you can easily create one from the Editable.

Comment: Editable can also contain markup, whereas a String cannot.